# Response is null while calling a php function in android using json

Tags: php, android, json, magento

I am trying to authenticate the user in magento for the android app.But the response in null.
On the php side:

```
<?php
require_once('http://carinopharmacy.com/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento    

umask(0); Mage::app();

$id = 1;

try{ $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($id)->authenticate($email, $password); }catch( Exception $e ){ $result = false; }
?>
```

On the android side:

```
    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSONObject request=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json_response=null;
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(Login_url);
    try
    {
    request.put("email", email_text);
    request.put("password", password_text);

    HttpResponse response;
    StringEntity entity=new StringEntity(request.toString());
    httppost.addHeader("content-type","application/json");  
    response=client.execute(httppost);      
    String response_string=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),HTTP.UTF_8);   
    if (response_string.equals("true")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login_activity.this, Main_activity.class));
    }
    else {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(Login_activity.this, "Email and password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is `$email, $password`? Where are they defined?

Comment: It's a built in function authenticate that has parameters email and password.

Comment: What are the **values** of `$email, $password` in your script?

Comment: There is no value assigned.I am not a php person.Is it necessery to define the variables?Is n't the values are replaced when I call the method.

Comment: This is programming basics. If variables are not defined - how can you get their values?

Comment: `require_once('http://carinopharmacy.com/Mage.php'); ` -- this is not the **path** you your Mage.php, this is a URL. PHP will make a HTTP request in this line, probably yielding a 403 forbidden response.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
'require_once('http://carinopharmacy.com/app/Mage.php');'is the correct path of mage.php.Trying it now.